# Finding a matrix that satisfy the following row and column requirements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

> Find a matrix A that satisfy the following requirement:
>
> $$ \text {col}(A)=\left\{\begin{matrix} (1,2,3)^T,(3,4,5)^T  \end{matrix}\right\}  \\(1,2,3)\in \text{row}(A)$$

So can I simply "build" the matrix from the columns and add a linearly dependent column like so:

$$ \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 2 &4 &4  \\3&6&5 \\ \end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @GitGud, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question so this doesn't come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 2 &4 &4  \\3&6&5 \\ \end{matrix}\right]$$

Is correct.